# Getting user's friend from facebook using as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

I have seen a flash game that retrieves user's friends list in the same application.

How is this possible? I've searched the code but I couldn't found it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a query?
Dowload the **[AS3 SDK for Facebook](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/list)**, you can also see some example at the link above.

Once you have dowload the library, you are going to use it in your project. 
Then you can use:

```
Facebook.fqlQuery("SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = " + IDutente +")",
    function(res:Object, fail:Object) {
        if (res != null)
            trace(res);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you start looking into this [API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/), supported by Adobe and Facebook. You will need however Adobe AIR, and in some cases, Flex.

If I find more sources/ideas, I will edit.

Comment: ya sir, thank you for your answer, i have already read it but i could not implement it in my code.